# Is there a solution for getting rid of the empty space generated by using 40% on a iframe when trying to control the size of the video?

Tags: html, css

```css
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}

main {
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width="52" height="26" viewBox="0 0 52 26" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3Cg fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"%3E%3Cg fill="%239C92AC" fill-opacity="0.4"%3E%3Cpath d="M10 10c0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6h2c0 2.21 1.79 4 4 4 3.314 0 6 2.686 6 6 0 2.21 1.79 4 4 4 3.314 0 6 2.686 6 6 0 2.21 1.79 4 4 4v2c-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6zm25.464-1.95l8.486 8.486-1.414 1.414-8.486-8.486 1.414-1.414z" /%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>A video!</p>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vbg81kc56FU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vbg81kc56FU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Nice! Aspect Ratio!</p>
</main>
```

Is there a solution for getting rid of the empty space generated by using 40% on a iframe when trying to control the size of the video? I have a problem where using 100% width and height gives me a video that's too big, I don't want to lose the responsiveness, but want to make the videos smaller. Is there a solution for this?

Is there a solution that also allows you to change the video sizes for larger screen sizes to make the video size responsive?

https://codepen.io/acodepen123/pen/bGWzagV

```
.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

I used this to make the video smaller by changing 100% to 40%, but this solution forces me to change the value of the padding between the videos and even then the margin increases and decreases in size. I am wondering if there's another way to change the size of the video without changing the width and height of the iframe.

Comment: The question isn't clear enough to me. What do you want different? In what way is the padding an issue?

Comment: Code must be shared on Stack Overflow, not only on CodePen. It would be preferable if it was in a Stack Snippet (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar).

Comment: Ability to make the video larger or smaller without leaving a huge gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. U need to make container for your wrappers:

Here is your code with changes:

```css
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}
.wrapper-container{
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width="52" height="26" viewBox="0 0 52 26" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3Cg fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"%3E%3Cg fill="%239C92AC" fill-opacity="0.4"%3E%3Cpath d="M10 10c0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6h2c0 2.21 1.79 4 4 4 3.314 0 6 2.686 6 6 0 2.21 1.79 4 4 4 3.314 0 6 2.686 6 6 0 2.21 1.79 4 4 4v2c-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4-3.314 0-6-2.686-6-6zm25.464-1.95l8.486 8.486-1.414 1.414-8.486-8.486 1.414-1.414z" /%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>A video!</p>
  <div class="wrapper-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vbg81kc56FU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vbg81kc56FU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <p>Nice! Aspect Ratio!</p>
</main>
```